# DocFX Documentation Missing for Event Parameters

Tags: c#, vb.net, docfx

I'm using DocFX framework to generate documentation for my .NET DLL. It gives a great experience with customization. However I'm just stuck with the fact that my public VB Events are included in documentation but the information related to parameters is missing.

For example for a method the documentation looks like:

**MethodName**

Some Description...

**Declaration**

Declaration Information

**Parameters**

A table listing all parameters, with type, name and description columns

However, for events with parameters, the table listing all parameters along with information is missing.

Any solution or workaround would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this information is shown, but not in the same page. For example, you can see eat event in [this page](http://docascode.github.io/docfx-seed/api/CatLibrary.ICat.html?q=event). Although parameters don't show, you can click on the Type `EventHandler` to see the parameters in [this delegate page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.eventhandler?view=netframework-4.7.2), where you can know its parameters are object sender, EventArgs e.